# Integrate MVC project to ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am assigned to do some requirements in MVC. And they want to integrate my project into the application which is already done in ASP.NET Core. Is it possible? How to achieve this?

I want the configuration settings. How to apply this in my project?

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET Core does offer an ASP.NET Core MVC project type - that sounds like exactly what you're looking for!

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to integrate mvc project to the exiting asp.net core app. below are the steps you can follow:

1)If you have an existing MVC project, ensure it targets .NET Core or a compatible version that can be referenced in your ASP.NET Core application.

- If starting from scratch, you can create a new MVC controller within your ASP.NET Core application directly.

2)**Startup.cs**: In the `ConfigureServices` method, you need to add MVC to the IServiceCollection using the `AddControllersWithViews`, `AddRazorPages`, or `AddMvc` method, depending on your needs.In the `Configure` method, ensure you define the routing for your MVC controllers using `app.UseEndpoints` and map controllers with `endpoints.MapControllerRoute` or similar.

3)**appsettings.json**: This file is used for storing configuration settings like database connections, API keys, and other settings. You can access these settings in your application through the `IConfiguration` interface.

4)If your MVC project uses Entity Framework, you will need to add your database context to the `ConfigureServices` method and configure it with the connection string from your `appsettings.json`.

5)ASP.NET Core has built-in support for dependency injection. You can configure your services in the `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs` and then inject them into your controllers.

6)Place your MVC views in the `Views` folder corresponding to the name of the controller.

- Static files like JavaScript, CSS, and images should go into the `wwwroot` directory.

Here is the sample Startup.cs file:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews(); 
        // ... other services like DbContext, etc.
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // ... error handling, etc.

        app.UseStaticFiles(); 

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```